# Why inline static type resolution does not work on List?

Tags: generics, f#, inline, typeclass

I'm trying to write an inline map function that can be used with any type that has `mapx` as a static member with following code:

```
type Container<'T> =
  { value: 'T }

type container<'a> = Container<'a>

type Container<'T> with
  static member mapx (f: 'T -> 'b,  x: 'T container) = { value=f(x.value) } // tuple form...

type List<'T> with
  static member mapx (f: 'T -> 'b, x: 'T list) = List.map f x

let inline map (f: ^a -> ^b) (x: ^t) =
  (^t: (static member mapx: (^a -> ^b) -> ^t -> ^c ) (f, x))  // (2) curry form

let plus2 = (+) 2

let x = { value=2 } |> map plus2  // ok
let y = [1;2;3] |> map plus2      // (1) Error... 

printfn "%A" x
printfn "%A" y
```

I have two questions:

**(1)** This line causes compiler warning, but the previous expression is ok!? The error message is

> The type 'int list' does not support operator `mapx`

Can anyone explain why it does not work on List but does work for Container? and what I have to do to make it work with List?

**(2)** Am I using the constraint correctly? I find that the constraint is written in curry form but the method has to be in tuple form... this is quite confused.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F# doesn't support statically resolved type constraints for extension members, that's why `List` doesn't work.

When the compiler can, it will compile extension-syntax members as normal members, and that's why `Container` works.

Comment: This is really tricky :'( btw, may you please answer the question 2 if you can? :)

Comment: Well, since it works for `Container`, it's safe to assume that the syntax is right.